# JavaScript postMesssage from parent to iframe not received

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, postmessage

I am building a WPF app and using the CefSharp control to host a webpage. The HTML that I am loading looks like this:

```
                "<HTML>" 
                "<head>" 
                    "<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=11' /> " 
                "</head>" 
                "<body>" 
                    "<script language='javascript'>" 
                        javaScriptForMessageListener 
                    "</script>" 
                    "<iframe id='remote-signature' " 
                        "class='remote-signature front displayNone' " 
                        "name='signatureFrame'" 
                        "width='1000' " 
                        "height='1000' " 
                        "referrerpolicy='unsafe-url'" 
                        "src=" _urlForSignaturePages 
                    "></iframe>" 
                "</body>" 
                "</HTML>"
```

The JavaScript looks like this:
...

```
function signatureFinish() {
    document.getElementById('remote-signature').contentWindow.postMessage('finishSignature', '*');
}
```

...

The _urlForSignaturePages brings in some pages and puts them in the iframe whose ID is 'remote-signature'.

When I invoke the signatureFinish() function from C#, the postMessage is not received in the pages in the iframe.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Open Devtools to see if there are errors https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging is it working in Chrome at the same version? CefSharp is a wrapper around the Chromium embedded framework. CEF has it's own support forum at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php

Comment: How do you open Devtools for a CefSharp control?

Thanks for the link to the CEF support forum. I will check it out.

Comment: I have it open now and I am looking for errors. thanks.